# if term reference is value X in tpl.php file

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I want it so that in my page.tpl.php file if the user has selected "Standard" as the "Page Type" term reference it prints an extra bit of html.

I tried something along the lines of the code below but have not had any luck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php $page_type = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_page_type');
if ($page_type == 'Standard') {
    print "worked";
} ?>
```

If I print the "field_page_type" value further down the page it prints "Standard" on the page but if I use the if statement above it doesn't print the "worked" result.

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

The above use of `field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_page_type');` is going to return an array that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 549
        )

)
```

But what you want is the value of the term so you'll need to do the following:

```
<?php $page_type = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_search_type');
if ($page_type['#items'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name == 'Standard') {
    print "worked";
} ?>
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect thank you. I changed "field_search_type" in your response to "field_page_type" and it worked as I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great and yes, apologies for leaving that. It was from testing on my end. Glad it worked for you!